Find PDF of $X/Y$ of two independent continuous random variables
This is the exercise $15$ of chapter $8.2$ from fundamentals of probability with stochastic processes $4$th.
Let $X$ and $Y$ be two independent random variables with the same probability density function given by
$$f(x) =
\begin{cases}
e^{-x}  & \text{if } 0 \lt x \lt \infty\\
0, & \text{elsewhere}
\end{cases}
$$
Show that $g$, the probability density function of $X/Y$, is given by
$$g(t) =
\begin{cases}
\frac{1}{(1+t)^2}  & \text{if } 0 \lt t \lt \infty\\
0, & t \le 0
\end{cases}
$$
My way of thinking is let $x = yt$ and $g(t) = \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-(yt+y)}\,dy$ but the answer is wrong.

You can find the CDF first, that is find $\Pr(X/Y\leq t)$, then differentiate it.

Consider the CDF of $X/Y$. Let $F_{X/Y}(t)$ be CDF of $X/Y$.
$$\begin{align}
F_{X/Y}(t)&=\Pr(X/Y\leq t)\\
&=\Pr(X\leq ty,Y>0)+\Pr(X\geq ty,Y<0)\\
&=\Pr(X\leq ty, Y>0)\\
&=\int_0^\infty\int_{-\infty}^{ty}f(x,y)\,dxdy\\
&=\int_0^\infty\int_{0}^{ty}e^{-x-y}\,dxdy\\
&=\int_0^\infty\left[-e^{-x-y}\right]_0^{ty}\,dy\\
&=\int_0^\infty -e^{-ty-y}+e^{-y}\,dy\\
&=\left[\frac{1}{t+1}e^{(-t-1)y}-e^{-y} \right]_0^\infty\\
&=-\frac{1}{t+1}+1
\end{align}$$
for $t>0$.
So PDF of $X/Y$ is $g(t)=F'_{X/Y}(t)=\frac{1}{(t+1)^2}$ for $t>0$; $0$ otherwise.
Note: $f(x,y)=f(x)f(y)$ because the two variables are independent.
